# How to have a left and right sidebar after main content?

Tags: html, css

I discovered that with massive negative percent margin one can achieve having left and sidebar *after* the main content in DOM but still have them appear right places:

(DOM order is fixed as following)

```
<div id="content">The main content</div>
<div id="left">Leftist</div>
<div id="right">Rightist</div>
<div id="footer">Footer</div>
```

Only CSS I could come up that gives left and right sidebar is following:

```
#content { 
    background: green; 
    float: right; width: 60%; margin-right: 20%; margin-left: -80%;
}
#right { 
    background: blue;
    width: 20%; float: right;
}
#left {
    background: red;
    width: 20%; float: left;
}
#footer {
    background: gray;
    clear: both;
}
```

But I'm not entirely sure is this preferred way to achieve this, but it worked, so is there anything wrong with it? (Above [is viewable in jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/DryJE/6/))

So is there other way to have have a #left and #right sidebar after main #content with CSS?

Comment: You don't even need the margins at all.  http://jsfiddle.net/DryJE/2/

Comment: @Sparky672, no. Order of DOM should not be changed. That was the whole point! Screen readers must read #content first.

Comment: Often, content in one column is not as important as content in another (for example, navigation vs. an article). Having relevant content higher on the page (in the markup) helps search engines find you. This is why grid systems like 960.gs have a push- and pull- feature to re-order grid elements.

Comment: @Matt Huh? That was the reason I said #left and #right must come after #content. Otherwise I would have done like Sparky said. But the purpose of my post it to ponder how to achieve left and right sidebar when DOM order is #content,#left,#right and my CSS above is the only way I discovered to do that.

Comment: Don't `float` `#content`.  It's already outside the flow so you could just use `absolute` instead.  http://jsfiddle.net/DryJE/4/

Comment: @Sparky672 surely position absolute for main content is can of worms? It kills the possibility to have a solid footer for example.

Comment: Not if you put it all in a wrapper.  Otherwise, write a more complete question.  Some argue that floats are a can of worms.

Comment: @Sparky672 I did add a footer yes, I suppose now position absolute is not a choice even.

Comment: And these are just comments...

Comment: I personally don't understand how that margin thing is working at all...

Comment: @Sparky672 your comments are appreciated nevertheless. I updated the jsfiddle link with longer content.

Comment: @Chris exactly, but it does! Even with IE9 in "IE7 mode". Thats why I'm asking is this standards compliant (as in advisable to do) as CSS is sometimes tricky business.

Comment: I'm guessing the way it works is to do with the fact that the margins and width add up to 0% so when floating the other elements it doesn't get in the way at all... And of course the fact it is floating means that left margin doesn't make a difference to its position... I'd personally put this in the category of "don't use it unless you really have to" and also do thorough cross browser testing on it since it feels like the kind of thing that could be unspecified behaviour. Hopefully somebody will suggest a better method though. :)

Comment: I changed the title, maybe it can be discussed better this way.

Comment: I'm not sure why this was closed. the question in its original form was asking if the use of negative margins was valid (whcih to my mind means is it standards compliant and/or will this render the same on all browsers)...

Answer (score 1):

If you use absolute positioning it will allow you to place them wherever you need without negative margins. Just use `left: X;` and `right: X;` to set the location on the page, where X is your value and units of measurement. However, doing so will require you to declare a height for your content so you know how far down to place the footer.